# How can I provide JSF2 with a custom PartialViewContext implementation?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I want to be able to process generic AJAX requests that do more than just updating an existent component. How can I override the default PartialViewContext in the FacexContext?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you can specify your own `PartialViewContextFactory` in the `faces-config` file, like this:

```
<faces-config ...>
    <application>
        <factory>
            <partial-view-context-factory>
                com.yourcompany.jsfextention.MyPartialViewContextFactory
            </partial-view-context-factory>
        </factory>
        ...
    </application>
    ...
</faces-config>
```